# How to grep with like in between 2 texts

Tags: java, unix

I have a log file which contains data like :

```
Customer=100000015 | AP ID=100000687 | StepID=N6MAAPtCzVYKFKVKMMQ | OA=107 | Activity=NegotiateProductConfigurationSyncImplAug | *** Starting Rule Debug Messages March 11, 2016 6:47:23 PM IST ***
```

I know the StepID but not the OA and Activity Name.

I want to do a like on grep to fetch everything after this line.

Like i will pass the StepID and "*** Starting Rule Debug Messages" to match the line.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach:

- iterate over the file line by line
- look for the StepID expression and remember the result
- if there was a hit in the past then capture every following line

e.g.

```
final String requiredStepId = "N6MAAPtCzVYKFKVKMMQ";

final List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/var/log/tool/output.log"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final List<String> resultLines = new LinkedList<>();

boolean match = false;
for (final String line : allLines) {
    if (line.contains("StepID=" + requiredStepId)) {
        match = true;
    }

    if (match) {
        resultLines.add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Display N lines after match:

-A is the option which prints the specified N lines after the match as shown below.

Syntax:
grep -A < N > "string" FILENAME

The following example prints the matched line, along with the 3 lines after it.

$ grep -A 3 -i "example" demo_text

Ref:http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/